# Visual Studio 2013 always starts with unwanted windows

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-setup

Using VS 2013 Community Edition (yay!), whenever I start it it opens the Performance Explorer window, which I do not require. I opened it once, and it seems to have saved this layout as default.

I have tried saving the setup without that window, locally overwriting the "CurrentSettings.vssettings", and if I expicitly reload the settings from there it is correct; however, if I close VS and open it again with a solution - Performance Explorer is back again.

Any ideas how/where to save my default settings?? Thanks!

Comment: Try Windows + Reset Window Layout.

Comment: That removes the unwanted window, but it returns as soon as I close VS, open it again, and open a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug appears to have existed for sometime, across many different versions (read comments)

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/749636/performance-explorer-window-is-always-opened-when-vs-is-started-and-mr-soln-opens

Answer (score 0):

Phill's link shows the Microsoft Bug, but you can get around this issue.

1. Go to the Visual Studio Project's folder
2. Close Visual Studio!!!
3. Remove the following file types: **Performance Reports** `*.vsp` and **Performance Sessions** `*.psess`
4. Re-open the Solution, you'll get an error saying Visual Studio could not find the Performance Reports for the Project. Do not worry; the Solution will still load.
5. Close the solution.
6. Re-open the solution - the *Performance Explorer* tab will be finally gone!